Widespread inconsistency in maximum likelihood estimation approach to logistic regression
I have found some widespread inconsistency in how the loss function of logistic regression is derived through the maximum likelihood estimation approach.
In the logistic regression model, we assume that $\Pr[Y = +1| X = x] = \sigma(w^T x)$, where $\sigma$ is the logistic function, $\sigma(w^T x) = \dfrac{\exp(w^T x)}{1 + \exp(w^T x)}$. Similarly, $\Pr[Y = -1| X = x] = 1 - \sigma(w^T x).$
$X, Y$ take on the usual meaning of example and label.
Observe that $w$ is a constant weight parameter (with no distribution assumed) which we wish to adjust. The most common way of finding $w$ is through maximum conditional likehood estimation.
This is where inconsistency occur in the literature: some authors assume $w$ is a random variable which we condition on, other assume $w$ is a constant parameter.
References that assume $w$ is a constant parameter:
https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2015fa/web/lecturenotes/lecturenote06.html
Note the author uses the colon notation to separate out random variable and constant parameters, i.e., $p(y|x; w)$
https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1178/lectureHandouts/220-logistic-regression.pdf
https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/250B/logreg.pdf
https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~xfern/classes/cs534-18/Logistic-Regression-3-updated.pdf
References that assume $w$ is a random variable:
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~awm/15781/slides/LogRegress-9-29-05.pdf
Note the author conditions on $w$, i.e.,  $p(y|x, w)$
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/mlbook/NBayesLogReg.pdf
https://zstevenwu.com/courses/s20/csci5525/resources/slides/lecture05.pdf
https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2018fa/lectures/lecturenote06.html
https://svivek.com/teaching/lectures/slides/logistic-regression/logistic-regression.pdf (the author uses both notation interchangeably)
This book: https://mml-book.github.io/
My questions are:

Which derivation is correct? Should $w$ be considered as a constant parameter or a random variable?

And just to clear up some confusion:

In maximum likelihood estimation, do we always maximize the likelihood with respect to a constant or do we maximize the likelihood with respect to a random variable?

Maybe a follow up to 2 is, in maximum a-posteriori estimation, do we always maximize the likelihood with respect to a constant or a random variable?

Could you show us how the likelihoods in the two cases "constant parameter" and "random variable" differ??

In maximum likelihood for logistic regression we do not model the weights as coming from any distribution: they should be considered as constant parameters.
That's how maximum likelihood works. You can do maximum likelihood for a problem that has randomly-distributed unobserved things in it, such as random effects linear models, but the maximising of the likelihood  isn't over those unobserved random quantities, it's over the parameters of the distribution. That is, the model might be
$$Y_{ij}=X_{ij}\beta+b_i+\epsilon_{ij}$$
where $\epsilon_{ij}\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $b_i\sim N(0,\tau^2)$ and you estimate $\beta$, $\sigma^2$ and $\tau^2$ by maximum likelihood, but not $b_i$.
I note that your references which say they are treating $w$ as a random variable often actually aren't when it comes to estimation.  You say that the first one conditions on $w$. So does the second (section 3.2). And the third. And then I stopped checking.

Thanks for the answer. To your last sentence, "say they are treating $w$ as a random variable but actually aren't", wouldn't notation such as $p(x|w)$ be confusing when $w$ is not (related to) random variable? I have never seen conditioning on a non-random variable.
